# Implementing a radar simulation

Tags: c#

I'm doing a project on radar simulation and i have to detect how fast a plane is flying using c#.

Is there a formula which I can use to calculate the distance and the speed?

Comment: Shouldn't you be providing **a lot** more information for this type of problem? What have you done so far?

Comment: im trying to find on the internet. but i cant seems to find any

Answer (score 4):

[image: radar simulation]

See the picture, R is the radar, P1 is the plane position at time 0, P2 is the plane position after time t. Since we know the speed of the radar wave in the air, we can calculate RP1 and RP2 easily. Also the angle P1RP2 is known, we can get length of P1P2 by [trigonometric function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions). so the speed of the plane is P1P2/t.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to determine the speed via radar. the one already mentioned, but also the change of frequency.

you might wanne check this out:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_radar

the distance between plane and radar is a result of the time used between transmitting and receiving.

d = c*t/2

Answer (score 0):

If you have two know two points where the plane has been, and the time difference between these references, then it is very possible.

Speed it easy, calculate the distance usin g pythagorus:

```
float dist = sqrt( sqr(x2-x1) + sqr(y2-y1) );
```

Direction is trickier, and requires some trig. Try searching the internet for the formula for direction between two points.

Comment: "Try searching the internet for the formula for direction between two points." --- `y = kx + b` or vector ;-)